# How can I list all implemented traits for a given type during compilation in a macro?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for a way to find all traits implemented for a given type, during compilation, for use within a macro.

My use case is that I'd like to write a macro that creates newtype structs and implements all inner type traits, or at least a subset of them.

Comment: You are trying to implement [*delegation*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2393).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

> ## [The Rustc Driver](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rustc-guide/rustc-driver.html):
>
> […] the main phases of the compiler are:
>
> 1. Parse Input: Initial crate parsing
> 2. Configure and Expand: Resolve `#[cfg]` attributes, name resolution, and **expand macros**
> 3. Run Analysis Passes: **Run trait resolution, typechecking**, region checking and other miscellaneous analysis passes on the crate
> 4. Translate to LLVM: Translate to the in-memory form of LLVM IR and turn it into an executable/object files

(emphasis is mine)

Macros are expanded before trait resolution is done, so at the time your macro is expanded, type information is unknown.